# Joomla 3 - gettin 1054 - Unknown column error

Tags: mysql, joomla, joomla3.0

I have this query:

```
$db = JFactory::getDbo();

        $query = $db->getQuery(true);

        $query->select($db->quoteName( array('#__content.id', '#__content.title', '#__content.introtext', '#__content.images', '#__content.catid', 'cat.alias') ))
        ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', '#__categories'))
        ->join('INNER', $db->quoteName('#__categories', 'cat') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('#__content.catid')  . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('cat.id') . ' )')
        ->where($db->quoteName('cat.alias') . ' = '  . $db->quote($alias) )
        ->order($db->quoteName('#__content.created'), ' DESC');
        $db->setQuery($query, 0, 4);

        $results = $db->loadObjectList();
```

When I try to run this query I get following error:

```
1054 - Unknown column 'tqei2_content.id' in 'field list'
```

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the database table names in the `select` and `order` parts of your query.

`#__content` and `#__categories` (#__ being the table prefix) is a table name and should only be used in the `->from()` and `->join()` sections.

Have a look at the Joomla documentation to get a good example of how it should look:

http://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase

Comment: So Joomla is using it's own logic. Nice :D. Thanks for helping me :).